R8 Issues after upgrading AGP 8 (google.protobuf and java.awt)
I'm having these reported Missing classes during building,
Missing class com.google.protobuf.java_com_google_android_gmscore_sdk_target_granule__proguard_group_gtm_N1281923064GeneratedExtensionRegistryLite$Loader (referenced from: java.util.List kotlinx.coroutines.internal.FastServiceLoader.load(java.lang.Class, java.lang.ClassLoader))
Missing class java.awt.Component (referenced from: long com.sun.jna.Native$AWT.getComponentID(java.lang.Object) and 3 other contexts)
Missing class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment (referenced from: long com.sun.jna.Native$AWT.getComponentID(java.lang.Object))
Missing class java.awt.HeadlessException (referenced from: long com.sun.jna.Native$AWT.getComponentID(java.lang.Object) and 5 other contexts)
Missing class java.awt.Window (referenced from: long com.sun.jna.Native$AWT.getWindowID(java.awt.Window) and 2 other contexts)
Missing class org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLParameters (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.BouncyCastlePlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List) and 1 other context)
Missing class org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLSocket (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.BouncyCastlePlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List) and 5 other contexts)
Missing class org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.BouncyCastlePlatform.<init>())
Missing class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt$Version (referenced from: boolean okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$Companion.atLeastVersion(int, int, int))
Missing class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt (referenced from: boolean okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$Companion.atLeastVersion(int, int, int) and 4 other contexts)
Missing class org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier (referenced from: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$DisabledHostnameVerifier)
Missing class org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.OpenJSSEPlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List))
Missing class org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.OpenJSSEPlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List) and 1 other context)
Missing class org.openjsse.net.ssl.OpenJSSE (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.OpenJSSEPlatform.<init>())

and I tried to supply the suggested -dontwarn from missing_rules.txt, but it sill having these missing classes errors.
I was able to fix the missing classes from org.bouncycastle all the way down to org.openjsse by updating okhttp from 4.9.1 to 4.12.0, taken from this github issue. Then after, I am left with these remaining missing classes
Missing class com.google.protobuf.java_com_google_android_gmscore_sdk_target_granule__proguard_group_gtm_N1281923064GeneratedExtensionRegistryLite$Loader (referenced from: java.util.List kotlinx.coroutines.internal.FastServiceLoader.load(java.lang.Class, java.lang.ClassLoader))
Missing class java.awt.Component (referenced from: long com.sun.jna.Native$AWT.getComponentID(java.lang.Object) and 3 other contexts)
Missing class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment (referenced from: long com.sun.jna.Native$AWT.getComponentID(java.lang.Object))
Missing class java.awt.HeadlessException (referenced from: long com.sun.jna.Native$AWT.getComponentID(java.lang.Object) and 5 other contexts)
Missing class java.awt.Window (referenced from: long com.sun.jna.Native$AWT.getWindowID(java.awt.Window) and 2 other contexts)

These -dontwarn rules doesn't seem to fix the errors,
-dontwarn com.google.protobuf.java_com_google_android_gmscore_sdk_target_granule__proguard_group_gtm_N1281923064GeneratedExtensionRegistryLite$Loader
-dontwarn java.awt.Component
-dontwarn java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
-dontwarn java.awt.HeadlessException
-dontwarn java.awt.Window

I suspect there is an outdated library in the project the same way I fixed the issue with okhttp. What can I try next?
Edit
I edited the question to ask what could be the possible outdated library I have to upgrade since I was able to fix the other Missing class errors by upgrading Okhttp and trying to put the generated warnings from missing_rules.txt to the proguard-rules file but with no success.

The -dontwarn directives you listed should silence the Missing class errors. Please double-check that you have them in the correct configuration file.

@sgjesse I made sure I put them in the proguard-rules.txt, and I was able to reduce the other Missing class errors by upgrading Okhttp, so I'm wondering what other library should I upgrade to remove these missing class errors
